# How to use maven test classes in main class

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am trying to create a test automation framework using Maven and TestNG. All the test classes in the application are written under `src/test/java` folder and all utility methods are written under `src/main/java`. I can run all the test scripts using `pom.xml` successfully. The framework also contains a main method from where `testng.xml` is created dynamically and the test classes are run. In the main method I am loading the test classes using below code

```
File classDir = new File("C:/workspace/myproject/target/test-classes/packagename/testScripts/"); //This is the path of all the compiled test classes
URL[] classUrl = {classDir.toURI().toURL()};
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classUrl);
Class<?> testClass=urlClassLoader.loadClass("packagename.testScripts.TestClassName");
```

but it throws exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: packagename.testScripts.TestClassName
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: You cant access test classes from a main module. Instead make another module, for example `myapp-test-lib` and put the classes there, in the `main` path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the FQN of your class which is `packagename.testScripts.TestClassName`, your `classDir` is not properly set it should rather be:

```
File classDir = new File("C:/workspace/myproject/target/test-classes/");
```